Rails join pluck wrong id
This likely duplicate, but
BananaStand has_many :banana_sale_tickets
BananaSaleTicket belongs_to :banana_stand
BananaSaleTicket belongs_to :buyer
Buyer has_many :banana_sale_tickets

previous_banana_buyers_ids = @banana_stand.banana_sale_tickets.joins(:buyer).pluck(:id)

I'd like the ids of the buyers, but it's giving me the ids of the banana_sales_tickets.
Both have :id. Code works if I select another attribute that is unique to Buyer

previous_banana_buyers_ids = @banana_stand.banana_sale_tickets.joins(:buyer).pluck('buyers.id')

Simpler than that @banana_stand.banana_sale_tickets.pluck(:buyer_id). No need to join the Buyer when you just want the id that BananaSaleTicket already has access to. Also depending on your implementation I would highly recommend select over pluck

Ty. I need an array of ids so pluck works. ... I can't ascertain from google any basic scenarios when select is applicable, or what is normally done with the returned array of activerecord relations (id nil)

@daveasdf_2 say you were doing something like ids = @banana_stand.banana_sale_tickets.pluck(:buyer_id) and then Buyer.where(id: ids). When translated to SQL this becomes buyers.id IN (# list of ids). This works fine today when you have 30 buyers, but what happens when you reach 100k+ buyer ids? Chances are your query will just stop working one day because you will have exceeded the length for a SQL query. If you used select well then this becomes buyers.id IN (# a subquery). This is not only better performing but future proof. So you say you need an Array but do you really?

I appreciate that and understand the issue and will transfer them all to select after some more research, primarily I don't know what to do with the return of a select. [     [0] #<BananaSaleTicket:0x0062818b9e3eb8> {            "id" => nil,         "email" => "email@email.com"     }, etc  ... it's an ActiveRecord::Relation, and asdf[0].class.name == "BananaSaleTicket", but it's not a full BananaSaleTicket, has id nil and all kinds of problems. I don't know how to assess the return, when it seems i just need an array. I'll put it on my to-do list queue tho

pluck(:id) fires query SELECT "table_name"."id" FROM "table_name"
and select(:id) also fires same query.
So if you want selective columns pluck is best.
and if you have complex conditions or perform calculations on the data while fetching from database select is best.

@user681 select does not "fire a query". This is what makes it better in a querying context. The query for select will only execute and "load" Objects when necessary. The reason one might think it executes a query is because in the console when you call select the console will then also output the result and this inspection causes the query to execute. For Example ids = MyClass.all.select(:id) in the console will execute a query at the point where it prints to the output stream but ids = MyClass.all.select(:id); true will output true and no query will be executed.

@engineersmnky Yes agreed, Select is a better choice for a larger table. However, for a table with fewer/limited records pluck makes more sense, as it saves an extra loop to get an array of IDs.
Also even if the data size is larger, we can combine pluck with in_batches and process the data batch-wise. This will help reduce the memory needs of the program as well while computing.

You can try below:
previous_banana_buyers_ids = @banana_stand.banana_sale_tickets.joins(:buyer).pluck('buyers.id').uniq

Hope this helps.
